# Create an online event using Microsoft Graph that links to an existing Teams meeting

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-teams, microsoft-graph-calendar

I know it is possible to [create an online event through Microsoft Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/graph/outlook-calendar-online-meetings?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5001655). What I want to do is create an event, mark it as online, but point it to an existing Microsoft Teams meeting, not create a new one.

I've tried settings `IsOnlineMeeting` and `OnlineMeetingProvider`, `OnlineMeetingUrl` and `OnlineMeeting` (with `ConferenceId` and `JoinUrl`), but when the request is POSTed, the response comes back with none of those set, and the meeting appears as just a regular non-online event.

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to make an event joinable in Teams using extended properties (`Event.SingleValueExtendedProperties`), though it's not officially supported as far as I know.

These extended properties are the main ones involved, but there may be more:

```
String {00020329-0000-0000-c000-000000000046} Name SkypeTeamsMeetingUrl
String {00020329-0000-0000-c000-000000000046} Name OnlineMeetingConfLink
String {00020329-0000-0000-c000-000000000046} Name SkypeTeamsMeetingETag
String {00020329-0000-0000-c000-000000000046} Name SchedulingServiceUpdateUrl
String {00020329-0000-0000-c000-000000000046} Name SchedulingServiceMeetingOptionsUrl
String {00020329-0000-0000-c000-000000000046} Name SkypeTeamsProperties
```

The value for `SkypeTeamsMeetingUrl` is the same as `onlineMeeting.joinUrl`.  The remaining properties have the same information formatted differently:

- O365 tenant ID
- Azure AD object ID of the user (oid)
- Online meeting thread ID

Example of what values these properties have (SkypeTeamsMeetingETag is blank):

```
Tenant ID: c825445b-b4dc-48b1-9455-2756e82f4ed1
User oid:  73a26776-6920-4f4d-8192-5b89da5868e7
Thread ID: 19:meeting_ZWMwODM1YzYtZTA5NS00MTc2LTlkMjgtOWM3NTE4OTZiNjA1@thread.v2

Id: String {00020329-0000-0000-c000-000000000046} Name SkypeTeamsMeetingUrl
Value: https://teams.microsoft.com/l/meetup-join/19%3ameeting_ZWMwODM1YzYtZTA5NS00MTc2LTlkMjgtOWM3NTE4OTZiNjA1%40thread.v2/0?context=%7b%22Tid%22%3a%22c825445b-b4dc-48b1-9455-2756e82f4ed1%22%2c%22Oid%22%3a%2273a26776-6920-4f4d-8192-5b89da5868e7%22%7d

Id: String {00020329-0000-0000-c000-000000000046} Name OnlineMeetingConfLink
Value: conf:sip:person@example.com;gruu;opaque=app:conf:focus:id:teams:2:0!19:meeting_ZWMwODM1YzYtZTA5NS00MTc2LTlkMjgtOWM3NTE4OTZiNjA1-thread.v2!73a2677669204f4d81925b89da5868e7!c825445bb4dc48b194552756e82f4ed1

Id: String {00020329-0000-0000-c000-000000000046} Name SkypeTeamsMeetingETag
Value: 

Id: String {00020329-0000-0000-c000-000000000046} Name SchedulingServiceUpdateUrl
Value: https://api.scheduler.teams.microsoft.com/teams/c825445b-b4dc-48b1-9455-2756e82f4ed1/73a26776-6920-4f4d-8192-5b89da5868e7/19_meeting_ZWMwODM1YzYtZTA5NS00MTc2LTlkMjgtOWM3NTE4OTZiNjA1@thread.v2/0

Id: String {00020329-0000-0000-c000-000000000046} Name SchedulingServiceMeetingOptionsUrl
Value: https://teams.microsoft.com/meetingOptions/?organizerId=73a26776-6920-4f4d-8192-5b89da5868e7&tenantId=c825445b-b4dc-48b1-9455-2756e82f4ed1&threadId=19_meeting_ZWMwODM1YzYtZTA5NS00MTc2LTlkMjgtOWM3NTE4OTZiNjA1@thread.v2&messageId=0&language=en-US

Id: String {00020329-0000-0000-c000-000000000046} Name SkypeTeamsProperties
Value: {"cid":"19:meeting_ZWMwODM1YzYtZTA5NS00MTc2LTlkMjgtOWM3NTE4OTZiNjA1@thread.v2","private":true,"type":0,"mid":0,"rid":0,"uid":null}
```